# How can I copy settings between IDE (WebStorm) projects?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm

I've got a WebStorm project (NodeJS) that I've configured to be as I want. But then I've created another project (JavaScript) that doesn't have any of the customizations I want, for example using ESLint to show code errors. How can I transfer all the settings from the first project to the second, is it possible even though they're both different types (NodeJS vs JavaScript)?

There's an import/export settings function in the IDE but that seems to be for global settings rather than project-specific ones.

Comment: Well, if anything -- all project-specific settings are stored in `.idea` subfolder of your project. P.S. `File | Default Settings` -- all settings set here will be applied to future new projects when they created.

Comment: So I've been using `File | Settings` this whole time rather than `File | Default Settings`. If project-specific settings are in `.idea` in the project, where are these default settings stored if you'd like to back them up when reinstalling the IDE.

Comment: It is stored together with other IDE-wide settings in one of the config files -- cannot say for 100% but most likely `project.default.xml` file (see the answer below .. or check this link: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)

Comment: And once again (just to make it clear): `File | Default Settings` will affect only future new projects -- it does nothing for already existing projects. **Also** keep in mind that not everything can be configured via `Default settings` -- only about 40-60% (my rough estimate) therefore copying individual config files between projects can make sense as well (in certain scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

IDE settings are stored in the dedicated directories under PhpStorm home directory. The PhpStorm directory name is composed of the product name and version.

For example:

Windows

`<User home>\.PhpStormXX\config` that contains user-specific settings.

`<User home>\.PhpStormXX\system` that stores PhpStorm data caches.

`<User home> in WindowsXP` is `C:\Documents and Settings\<User name>\;` in Windows Vista it is `C:\Users\<User name>\`

Linux

`/.PhpStormXX/config that contains user-specific settings.
~/.PhpStormXX/system that stores PhpStorm data caches.`

OS X

`~/Library/Application Support/PhpStormXX` contains the catalog with plugins.

`~/Library/Preferences/PhpStormXX` contains the rest of the configuration settings.

`~/Library/Caches/PhpStormXX` contains data caches, logs, local history, etc. These files can be quite significant in size.

`~/Library/Logs/PhpStormXX` contains logs.
Locations of directories

The config directory has several subfolders that contain xml files with your personal settings. You can easily share your preferred keymaps, color schemes, etc. by copying these files into the corresponding folders on another PhpStorm installation.

Prior to copying, make sure that PhpStorm is not running, because it can erase the newly transferred files before shutting down.

The following is the list of some of the subfolders under the config folder, and the settings contained therein.

Folder name User Settings
codestyles  Contains code style schemes.
colors  Contains editor colors and fonts customization schemes.
filetypes   Contains user-defined file types.
inspection  Contains code inspection profiles.
keymaps Contains PhpStorm keyboard shortcuts customizations.
options Contains various options, for example, feature usage statistics and macros.
templates   Contains user-defined live templates.
tools   Contains configuration files for the user-defined external tools.
shelf   Contains shelved changes.

Locations of the config, system, plugins directories can be modified in idea.properties file.

PhpStorm makes it possible to change *.vmoptions and idea.properties files without editing them in the PhpStorm installation folder.

Read more at this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/project-and-ide-settings.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Are the settings you're talking about the global IDE settings rather than the project-specific settings? The first project has the configuration I want, I need to get it into the second project.

Comment: Project settings are stored under .idea folder, global settings are stored at /home/<user>/.PhpStorm<version>/